# Clearing the attribute locations in OpenGL Shader

Tags: java, opengl, shader, lwjgl, vao

Is there a way to overwrite or clear an attribute location in OpenGL?
For example (I'm using lwjgl) I render something like this:

```
public void render(int vaoID, int vertexCount, int shaderProgramID){
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

    GL20.glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, 0, "position");
    GL20.glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, 1, "normal");

    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

and after that I want to run the next code with the same shaderProgramID

```
public void render(int vaoID, int vertexCount, int shaderProgramID){
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

    //this previously was position
    GL20.glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, 0, "normal");
    //and this was the normal
    GL20.glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, 1, "position");

    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

As you can see i changed the following code from this:

```
GL20.glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, 0, "position");
GL20.glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, 1, "normal");
```

to this:

```
GL20.glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, 0, "normal");
GL20.glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, 1, "position");
```

But when i run both of the code, the

```
GL20.glGetAttribLocation(programID, "position");
```

returns 0 instead of 1

Is there a way to clear the previously bound locations so that I can bind new ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must re-link your program after binding attribute locations. This is outlined in the documentation for `glBindAttribLocation (...)` as follows:

> ### Name
>
> > **[glBindAttribLocation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBindAttribLocation.xhtml)** — Associates a generic vertex attribute index with a named attribute variable
> >
> > #### C Specification
> >
> > > void glBindAttribLocation(   GLuint program,
> > >           GLuint index,
> > >           const GLchar *name);
> >
> > #### Description
> >
> > > [...]
> > >
> > > Attribute variable name-to-generic attribute index bindings for a program object can be explicitly assigned at any time by calling `glBindAttribLocation`. ***Attribute bindings do not go into effect until `glLinkProgram` is called.*** After a program object has been linked successfully, the index values for generic attributes remain fixed (and their values can be queried) until the next link command occurs.
> > >
> > > ***Any attribute binding that occurs after the program object has been linked will not take effect until the next time the program object is linked.***

Comment: Thank you for the answer, everything works fine. The only problem is that my uniform variables get cleared every time i run glLinkProgram. Is there a way to keep them while resetting the attribute locations?

Comment: @user370001: That behavior is undefined by the specification. I would say no. The values of your uniforms may remain the same or it may change, there's no way to control what happens to data in a program after it's re-linked. As a general rule you shouldn't be changing attribute binding locations frequently anyway - you might be better off refactoring some code to avoid having to do this.

Comment: I want to make it as fast as i can so i'll figure some other way to do this. Anyways thank you for the answer.

Comment: Put your uniforms in a uniform block backed by a buffer object. Then they exist separately from the program (and can be shared by multiple programs) and you'll just have to call glUniformBlockBinding again when you relink the program.